# Samples and tutorials for components for Modeling, MindMapping, etc

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface, components, gdi+

I want to have a graphical component with which I can create models, link them together with lines/curves, collapse/expand child nodes etc.

Something like the **EF & DataSet visual designers** and **MindMapping/BrainStorming applications**.

Any samples/tutorials would be great both for **WinForms/WPF** or **WebApps** to give me some ideas how I can go about creating such components.

Answer (score 1):

Below link is not component Its an open source project might be useful
[PlantUML Editor: A Fast and Simple UML Editor using WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/smart/plantumleditor.aspx)

> PlantUML Editor, built using WPF and .NET 3.5, is an IDE for drawing
>   UML diagrams using the amazing PlantUML tool. If you have used
>   PlantUML before, you know you can code UML diagrams super fast without
>   struggling with a designer environment. Especially those who use Visio
>   to draw UML diagrams (God forbid!), you will be in heaven. This is a
>   super fast way to get your diagrams up and ready for show. You can
>   *write* UML diagrams in plain English, following a simple syntax and
>   get diagrams generated on-the-fly.
>   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Well I think the first thing would be to choose one of the frameworks initially, because it'd be very different in each of the ones you mention.

For WPF I'd start by having a play around with shapes, geometry, and canvas. Maybe this might get you started...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx

Comment: yea it'd be very different in each framework, but preferably WebForms. btw tnx for the link but i know a bit about WPF .. the thing is that ive been playing with this idea for a while now and i can create simple graphics, link 'em together with lines/curves and move them around, but there are a lot of situations where my solutions will run into trouble .. so im looking for a well proven/generic approach to make such components.